# Stop jQuery autocomplete to filter/search results and populate the entire source array data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

**Problem:**

I am using [jQuery autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) for input type text.

I do not want to filter/search the results based on input and want to display all the source array values as suggestions. Any idea how to achieve this?

Is there a a method/alternative to just populate an entire array data source as suggestions without searching or flltering?

**Tech note:**

- I'm actually using an onkeyup/press event in my input[text] which calls an ajax. Upon ajax success the autocomplete is called.
- jQuery v1.10.2
- Query UI v1.11.3

**Code sample:**

```
var pr_suggst= new Array();

for(var i=0; i< scnt; i++)
    pr_suggst[i]= {value:availableTags[i]['name'], idx:availableTags[i]['id']};

$("#text_inp_id").autocomplete({source: pr_suggst});
```

Thanks you.

Comment: why use autocomplete if you don't want to use it?

Comment: I guess you need to show a list of suggestions when a user starts typing. That's a matter of adding a class on the list when the input's val is not `""`

Comment: skip405, I just want to use the ui of the autocomplete with the suggestion dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to not filter the contents, so that just make the request.term as empty

```
source: function( request, response ) {

      response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
      availableTags, "" ) ); // here
    },
```

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLp68/8/)